# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I fix this? I'm getting an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null`.

```js
client.on('ready', message  => {
  client.user.setActivity("21"+`${client.guilds.size} servers have members`+" "+"5"+`${client.users.size}`+` | !help `, { type: 'WATCHING' })
  console.log("21"+`${client.guilds.size} servers have members `+" "+"5"+`${client.users.size}`) 
});
```

Comment: It seems that `client.user` has a `null` value, but we need more context to know how to help you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BMiMwshE

Comment: help me plase TT i don't know how to fix

Comment: You could include some `console.log(client.user)` before of each `setActivity()` so you know which one is causing the error and what value it has in other parts of the bot app. Also, you can check this example bot for Discord, it may have something yours don't: https://gist.github.com/eslachance/3349734a98d30011bb202f47342601d3

Comment: can you help me?? see this picture

Comment: @BeamKunGzMARK you deleted the pastebin and gyazo posts, you need to edit extra information/context into the question, don't send them through pastebin links/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix i'm use new TOKEN(New bot)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Client` is logged in. That is the only way I could think those properties would be null.